# Calling multiple AJAX calls same function one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a load_graphs function which does a AJAX call creates a graphs.

The `load_graphs` function needs to be called multiple times to generate period for different regions as given below.

Even though the calls are done sequentially using a wrapper function, its called async. How can I call one by one the same AJAX function.

```
function load_all_graphs(){
    load_graphs('national','','container-natl-rates','container-natl-counts')
    load_graphs('division','Western','container-west-rates','container-west-counts')
}

load_all_graphs()


var load_graphs = function(scope, scopeFilter, chart_1, chart_2){
            d = new Date()
            starttime = d.setMonth(d.getMonth()-1)
            starttime = d.setDate(d.getDate()-1)
            endtime = (new Date).getTime()
            // console.log('starttime == ', starttime)
            // console.log('endtime == ', endtime)
            if (scope == 'national'){
                url = 'http://99.88.53.222:8081/vp.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Metrics?scope='+ scope + '&interval=day&startTime='+starttime+'&endTime='+ endtime
            }else {
                url = 'http://99.88.53.222:8081/vp.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Metrics?scope=' + scope + '&scopeFilter=' + scopeFilter + '&interval=day&startTime='+starttime+'&endTime='+ endtime
            }
            if (scopeFilter == ''){
                data_filter = 'national'
            }
            else if  (scopeFilter == 'Western'){
                data_filter = 'Western'
            }

            $.ajax({type:'GET',
                url: url,             
                // async: false,           
                success: function(data){                    
                    // console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                    // console.log(data)
                    $.each(data,function(i,x){                    
                        console.log('national == ', x[0]['X1'])                                                
                        console.log('national data_filter == ', data_filter)                                                
                        console.log('national == ', x[0]['X1'][data_filter])                                                

                        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                        {   
                            error_counts_results[i] = []
                        }
                        $.each(x[0]['X1'][data_filter], function(unix_date,data){                                
                            if  (parseFloat(unix_date)){
                                $.each(error_constants, 
                                    function(ix,error_item){  
                                        // console.log(ix)
                                        // console.log(data[error_item])
                                        error_counts_results[ix].push([parseInt(unix_date),data[error_item]])
                                    }
                                )
                            // console.log('result == ', JSON.stringify(error_counts_results))
                            }                           
                        })
                    })
                    seriesOptions[0] = {
                        name: error_constants[5],
                        data: error_counts_results[5]
                    };
                    console.log('option 1 == ', seriesOptions[0])
                    seriesOptions[1] = {
                        name: error_constants[0],
                        data: error_counts_results[0]
                    };
                    console.log('option 2 == ', seriesOptions[1])
                    seriesOptions[2] = {
                        name: error_constants[3],
                        data: error_counts_results[3]
                    };
                    console.log('option 3 == ', seriesOptions[2])
                    params = {
                        'title':'National'
                        ,'y2axis':'pct'
                    }                                 
                    createChart_National(chart_1,params);
                    seriesOptions[0] = {
                        name: error_constants[4],
                        data: error_counts_results[4]
                    };

                    seriesOptions[1] = {
                        name: name,
                        data: error_counts_results[1]
                    };

                    seriesOptions[2] = {
                        name: name,
                        data: error_counts_results[2]
                    };
                    params = {
                        'title':'National'
                        ,'y2axis':'cnt'
                    }                                 
                    createChart_National(chart_2,params);

                },                
            })

        }
```

Comment: Are you using Angular, and what is the problem? Do you want to await them or something?

Comment: Read about promises to chain async calls.

Comment: @DanielB That question recommended me for generic function to be called one by one..I implemented the same but still its called async.

Comment: Instead of posting an almost duplicate question, you should respond in your other question and explain if there is something wrong. At least tell the one who answered if it was helpful, and if so, mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @DanielB The reason I opened a new questions is bcuz here I have more information needed for better clarity but anyway ill respond to that question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use promises to chain your ajax calls together, jQuery already has this built into the ajax function.

```
$.ajax({ // ... })
.then (function (arg)
{
   // do something with arg
})
.then (function(){

  return $.ajax({ }); // second ajax call, return the promise 

})
.done (function(args)
{
    // do something with your final result
});
```

If you want to run the requests in parallel look into using promise.all

In general I would recommend reading about promises, here is a good place to start http://dailyjs.com/2014/02/20/promises-in-detail/